# how to build angular 7 project with lazy load modules

Tags: angular7

I just noticed that for Angular 7, if I am building the project with this:
`ng build --aot`, then all fine, and it will generate all the lazy loaded modules separately, but if I use this: `ng build --prod`, then the lazy loaded module is NOT generated at all under `dist` folder.

I checked the doc, they said using `--lazyModules` options, but I tried a lot by passing the lazy module as its value like below:

```
ng build --aot --progress=true --optimization=true --lazyModules=modules/home/home.module
```

it is useless and give me error as below:

> ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/projects/projectname/source/projectnamesrc/app/modules/modules/home/home.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Users/projects/projectname/source/projectname/$$_lazy_route_resource'

So if I am using lazyloading, can I still use `--prod` parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng build --base-href /ProjectName/ --prod --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk
```